# getting javadoc to work with netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

Hello I'm trying to make it so I can look at the javadoc with autocomplete in netbeans 6.7.1 but it tells me "javadoc not found". I tried adding it with the platform manager (I added c:/sun/SDK/docs/api) but it still doesn't work? What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Try to download the javadoc (from [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp)), copy the **zip** file to a folder of your choice and configure the javadoc in Java platforms as follow:

   [image]
2. If it still doesn't work, try to delete `%USERPROFILE%\.netbeans\6.7\var\cache`